# How to add a number on List in Scala(Beginner)

Tags: scala

I am just started learning Scala. I want to add numbers through loop and want to find out the minimum number. So, I did this

```
for(j<-0 until numberOfQuery){
      val z = readLine.split(" ");
      var from = Integer.parseInt(z(0));
      var to = Integer.parseInt(z(1));
      var i=from;
      var getNumber = List[Int](to+1);
      var counter = 0;
      for(i <-from until to+1){
          getNumber.apply(storeElemets(i));
          System.out.println(storeElemets(i));
      }
      System.out.println(getNumber.min);
    }
```

for input `10 20 30 40 11 22 33 44 15 5` and `0 5` the minimum number will be `10`. But, it returning `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So,

1) What is the correct way to declare a `List` in Scala?
2) What is my mistake ? What is the right way to add numbers.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is `10 20 30 40 11 22 33 44 15 5` and what is `0 5`? You are reading just one line per each `j` loop. How should the output be 10?

Comment: Can you write what you are trying to do in Java?

Answer (score 3):

`List` is an immutable [single linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list).

With `List[Int](i)` you are creating a list with a single element (`i`):

```
List(5)
//res0: List[Int] = List(5)
```

Actually you are calling a factory method `List.apply`. See [object `List` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List%24).

You should use `Nil` as an empty list:

```
var getNumber: List[Int] = Nil
// or
var getNumber = List.empty[Int]
```

With `getNumber.apply(n)` (or `getNumber(n)`) you are trying to selects an element by its index in the list. See [`List` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). So you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` here with `n > getNumber.size`.

You could prepend element to list using `::` method like this:

```
getNumber = storeElemets(i) :: getNumber
// with syntax sugar:
getNumber ::= storeElemets(i)
```

Note that `List` is immutable - you can only create a new list.

You could use `from to to` instead of `from until to+1`. Method `to` (and `until`) creates a [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range). You could use method `map` on any scala collection (including `Range`) like this:

```
val getNumber = (from until to).map{i => storeElemets(i)}
// with for-comprehensions:
val getNumber = 
  for {
    i <- from until to
  } yield storeElemets(i)
```

Note that `map` on `Range` creates `IndexedSeq` instead of `List`. You don't need `List` in this example, but if you need `List` you can convert collection to `List` using method `toList`:

```
val myList = getNumber.toList
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can declare your list using `List(10, 20, 30, 40, 11, 22, 33, 44, 15, 5)`. You can build a list from any collection by the method `.toList` append to it.
2. Your first mistake is that you do not create a list of size to+1, it just creates a list with a single element which is to+1. Try [`List.fill(to+1)(0)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List%24) to fill a list with to+1 zeros.

Besides, forget about semicolons and use `val` instead of `var` so that you ensure immutability, which is very convenient for high-scale programs.

`storeElemets` is undefined, but if it returns `i`, then at the second iteration the index is too high for the singleton list `getNumber`

1. If the input is the following:

   0 5 10 20 30 40 11 22 33 44 15 5
   a b

where a and b are the lower and upper index of the considered list, then you should do the following:

```
  val z = readLine.split(" ")
  val from = z(0).toInt
  val to = z(1).toInt
  val getNumber = z.toList.drop(2).drop(from).take(to-from+1)
  val sum = getNumber.sum // Equivalent to getNumber.foldLeft(0){ case (res, n) => res + n }
  println(sum)
  println(getNumber.min)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a builder if you really want:

```
val b = List.newBuilder[Int] // creates a list builder

for(i <-from until to+1){
  b += storeElemets(i) // stores an element
  println(storeElemets(i))
}

b.result() // you need to call it to retrieve a collection from builder
```

P.S. There is no need (and even not recommended in scala style guide) to use `;` at line ends. Also, you can call `println` without class definition.

Answer (score 1):

On top of other issues people have noted (mutability vs. immutability, semicolons, not knowing what `storeElemets` does, etc.) You've also chosen some ambiguous and difficult value names that clash with common terms and help make this code difficult to read.

Reading between the lines it looks as though `storeElemets` is what you are calling your "input"

My take would be something like this:

```
val storeElemets = IndexedSeq(10,20,30,40,11,22,33,44,15,5) //immutable

for(qry <- 0 until numberOfQuery) {
  val elems = readLne split " " //split into an array
  val Array(start, end) = elems take 2 map (_.toInt) //pattern matching

  val stored = (start to end) map storeElemets //also immutable
  //alternatively, this is more efficient in *most* cases...
  val stored = storeElemets drop start take (end-start+1)

  //println is a *side effect*, so we want to isolate it from the other logic
  stored foreach println
  println(stored.min)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
for(j<-0 until numberOfQuery){
  val lineSum = readLine.split(" ").map { _.toInt }.sum
  println(s"lineSum = $lineSum")
}
```

which for each string line read, splits the string by the space, parses each split item into an integer, and finally sums up all the integer values and prints the result.

Answer (score 0):

Beeing just a bit above a beginner, i will try to answer your Questions:

**1) What is the correct way to declare a List in Scala?**

There are some correct ways, for example:

val numbersList = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 11, 22, ...)

val numbersList = 10 :: 20 :: 30 :: 40 :: ... :: Nil

**2) What is my mistake ?**

You should notice that scala is in some aspects very different from other programming languages. One aspect is that you are not supposed to use var's (Variables), only val's.
This is because in scala you can have operations that work in parallel, and this can not be accomplished with variables (or it is at least very difficult). 
So one very importend point in using scala is:

Don't use variables (unless you absolutely have to) !!!

As it turns out, variables are not necesseay most of the time. But to programm without variables one has to learn some things from the beginning again (This was at least my experience). 
So a val (Value) is an immutable object that can not be changed once you defined it. And this is also true for a List object.
That means, once you define the list-object numbersList with:

val numbersList = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 11, 22, ...)

you can not change it, and this is the way you are supposed to work in scala.
You can change one item in the numbersList, but then you get a complete new List with only that one item changed as a result.
As a result of this, you are not supposed to use loops either (because for a loop you need a counter variable).
And the for-construkt used with vars isn't a loop after all but an expression that is translated in to an expression with map, flatMap and filter (and that can run in parallel)

**3) What is the right way to add numbers?**

In the case of a given List object numbersList from above, it is just

val result = numbersList.sum

I think it is very hard to learn scala when you know one or some computer languages and try to transfer your knowledge of this languages to scala, because of the conceptional differences.

Insted i would recommend the free online-course on coursera: "functional programming principles in scala" given by Prof. Martin Odersky, the inventor of scala.

Of course anyone can use a computer-language the way he wants, but it is sometimes good to know the way a language is meant to be used, to get the best out of it.